# How to define 'Short' name of selected element in ComboBox header

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, combobox

I work with Silverlight 4. There is a ComboBox that contains list of items. These items have "ToString()":

```
public class SquadFlangViewModel
{
    static SquadFlangViewModel()
    {
        int iFlangValuesCount = (typeof(TacticGameFlangFlangEnum)).GetFields().Length;
        Names = new string[iFlangValuesCount];
        Names[(int)TacticGameFlangFlangEnum.Usual] = "Равномерно";
        Names[(int)TacticGameFlangFlangEnum.Left] = "Левый";
        Names[(int)TacticGameFlangFlangEnum.Center] = "Центр";
        Names[(int)TacticGameFlangFlangEnum.Right] = "Правый";
        Names[(int)TacticGameFlangFlangEnum.Sides] = "Фланги";
        Names[(int)TacticGameFlangFlangEnum.LeftAndCenter] = "Левый и Центр";
        Names[(int)TacticGameFlangFlangEnum.RightAndCenter] = "Правый и Центр";

        ShortNames = new string[iFlangValuesCount];
        ShortNames[(int)TacticGameFlangFlangEnum.Usual] = "=";
        ShortNames[(int)TacticGameFlangFlangEnum.Left] = "Л";
        ShortNames[(int)TacticGameFlangFlangEnum.Center] = "Ц";
        ShortNames[(int)TacticGameFlangFlangEnum.Right] = "П";
        ShortNames[(int)TacticGameFlangFlangEnum.Sides] = "Ф";
        ShortNames[(int)TacticGameFlangFlangEnum.LeftAndCenter] = "ЛЦ";
        ShortNames[(int)TacticGameFlangFlangEnum.RightAndCenter] = "ПЦ";
    }

    public SquadFlangViewModel(TacticGameFlangFlangEnum eVal) { _eVal = eVal; }

    public TacticGameFlangFlangEnum Value { get { return _eVal; } }

    private static readonly string[] Names;

    private static readonly string[] ShortNames;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Names[(int)_eVal];
    }

    public string ShortName
    {
        get
        {
            return ShortNames[(int)_eVal];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I bind elements:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Flangs, Mode=OneTime}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Flang, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

The problem that ComboBox is in grid cell that is pretty narrow and I when item is selected I would like to display not a LONG description, but a short one.

That sounds like I should specify ComboBox to use 'ShortName' property when element is displayed as selected.

**How can I specify ComboBox to use ShortName property to display selected element when ComboBox is collapsed?**

Any ideas and other feedback is very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Try to DisplayMemberPath, it display shortnames.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Flangs, Mode=OneTime}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Flang, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="ShortNames"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using different templates for the combo box when it is expanded verses when it is collapsed. The following link shows an example for WPF: [Code Project example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47923/Using-a-different-DataTemple-when-a-WPF-ComboBox-i)